# how to calculate difference between two text value in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

how two calculate difference between two value in excel, is there a formula to do that

```
90123567.....90123569......difference=(1)
901123567....90123567......diffidence=(1)
```

thanks.

Comment: Where does the **1** come from? It is not the position of the difference and not the difference itself (in the first example). Perhaps it is the number of differences...? If you are looking to reiteratively compare two numbers or strings to see if each digit or character is the same then you would be better off with VBA. In the second example, isn't every digit 'not-the-same' after the first rogue 1 or are you expecting the comparative position to shift for each 'not-found' digit?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps what you are looking for is the Levenshtein Distance -- *the Levenshtein distance between two words is the minimum number of single-character edits (i.e. insertions, deletions or substitutions) required to change one word into the other*

The following UDF can compute that, but I have not tested it extensively.  And the URL where I found it is now defunct.  It does give the answers you show for the strings of digits you provide.

---

```
Option Explicit

'********************************
'*** Compute Levenshtein Distance
'********************************

Public Function LD(ByVal s As String, ByVal t As String) As Long
Dim d() As Long ' matrix
Dim m As Long ' length of t
Dim n As Long ' length of s
Dim i As Long ' iterates through s
Dim j As Long ' iterates through t
Dim s_i As String ' ith character of s
Dim t_j As String ' jth character of t
Dim cost As Long ' cost

  ' Step 1
  n = Len(s)
  m = Len(t)
  If n = 0 Then
    LD = m
    Exit Function
  End If
  If m = 0 Then
    LD = n
    Exit Function
  End If
  ReDim d(0 To n, 0 To m) As Long

  ' Step 2
  For i = 0 To n
    d(i, 0) = i
  Next i

  For j = 0 To m
    d(0, j) = j
  Next j

  ' Step 3
  For i = 1 To n
    s_i = Mid$(s, i, 1)

    ' Step 4
    For j = 1 To m
      t_j = Mid$(t, j, 1)

      ' Step 5
      If s_i = t_j Then
        cost = 0
      Else
        cost = 1
      End If

      ' Step 6
      d(i, j) = Minimum(d(i - 1, j) + 1, d(i, j - 1) + 1, d(i - 1, j - 1) + cost)

    Next j
  Next i

  ' Step 7
  LD = d(n, m)
  Erase d
End Function

'*******************************
'*** Get minimum of three values
'*******************************

Private Function Minimum(ByVal a As Long, _
                         ByVal b As Long, _
                         ByVal c As Long) As Long
Dim mi As Long

  mi = a
  If b < mi Then
    mi = b
  End If
  If c < mi Then
    mi = c
  End If

  Minimum = mi

End Function
```

---

Answer (score 1):

The following formula is what you're looking for :

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B1,A1,"")
```

Reference: [SUBSTITUTE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/substitute-function-2bdd8fb3-d756-4656-8aa4-e871e6578671)

Comment: The updated support.office documentation for that is at [SUBSTITUTE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/substitute-function-2bdd8fb3-d756-4656-8aa4-e871e6578671).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, didn't realize the link had changed, just copy pasted from somewhere!

Comment: thanks but ,it is not give me the difference between these two , I want to get the difference between two for example ID,in terms of the place of each digit

Comment: I want to get 1 in here.

Comment: Maybe this link will help [Magic Link](http://www.mrexcel.com/archive/Formulas/2878.html).